# Customize OID of snmp in linux

Tags: linux, snmp, mib, oid

Iwant to add an custom OID to MIB tree structure. I add the line as below to file /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

```
extend    test1   /bin/echo  Hello, world!
```

but I don't know how to specifiy the exact OID number. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, for example when I want to graph more fancy disk usage with say, [iostat](https://github.com/markround/Cacti-iostat-templates) I have

`pass .1.3.6.1.3.1 /usr/bin/perl /usr/local/bin/iostat.pl`

at the bottom of my `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`

then I can use `snmpwalk -v2c -cpublic localhost snmpwalk -v2c -cpublic localhost .1.3.6.1.3.1`

Comment: I did as your answer, but when I restart snmpd service, I received the error: /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 154: Error: unknown monitor OID

Comment: Well what's the full line now? You may need to use the experimental tree like above rather than something that's probably allocated to an enterprise but I'm not sure.

Comment: Here is my line: pass .1.3.6.1.3.1 /bin/sh /etc/snmp/scripts/postgresfiles.sh, and the error become /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 154: Error: unknown payload OID